# Can I send data to ble 4.2 or ble 5 module after pairing same as bluetooth classic and without using GATT connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

My endpoint device is a BLE 4.0 or BLE 4.2 or BLE 5 module

Android recommends to use the GATT connection to send data to BLE devices as according to this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le

My Question here is If I paired my phone with ble 4.2/5 module from Settings App in android phone then, Can I send data to ble module using the same process and code which is used in  Bluetooth Classic: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

example:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothService";
    private static final boolean D = true;
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_CONNECTION_LOST = 5;
    public static final int MESSAGE_UNABLE_CONNECT = 6;
    private static final String NAME = "BTPrinter";
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private BluetoothService.AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
    private BluetoothService.ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothService.ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState = 0;
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;

    public BluetoothService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        this.mHandler = handler;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isAvailable() {
        return this.mAdapter != null;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isBTopen() {
        return this.mAdapter.isEnabled();
    }

    public synchronized BluetoothDevice getDevByMac(String mac) {
        return this.mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mac);
    }

    public synchronized BluetoothDevice getDevByName(String name) {
        BluetoothDevice tem_dev = null;
        Set pairedDevices = this.getPairedDev();
        if(pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            Iterator var5 = pairedDevices.iterator();

            while(var5.hasNext()) {
                BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice)var5.next();
                if(device.getName().indexOf(name) != -1) {
                    tem_dev = device;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return tem_dev;
    }

    public synchronized void sendMessage(String message, String charset) {
        if(message.length() > 0) {
            byte[] send;
            try {
                send = message.getBytes(charset);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var5) {
                send = message.getBytes();
            }

            this.write(send);
            byte[] tail = new byte[]{10, 13, 0};
            this.write(tail);
        }

    }

    public synchronized Set<BluetoothDevice> getPairedDev() {
        Set dev = null;
        dev = this.mAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        return dev;
    }

    public synchronized boolean cancelDiscovery() {
        return this.mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    public synchronized boolean isDiscovering() {
        return this.mAdapter.isDiscovering();
    }

    public synchronized boolean startDiscovery() {
        return this.mAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        this.mState = state;
        this.mHandler.obtainMessage(1, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    public synchronized int getState() {
        return this.mState;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d("BluetoothService", "start");
        if(this.mConnectThread != null) {
            this.mConnectThread.cancel();
            this.mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if(this.mConnectedThread != null) {
            this.mConnectedThread.cancel();
            this.mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if(this.mAcceptThread == null) {
            this.mAcceptThread = new BluetoothService.AcceptThread();
            this.mAcceptThread.start();
        }

        this.setState(1);
    }

    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        Log.d("BluetoothService", "connect to: " + device);
        if(this.mState == 2 && this.mConnectThread != null) {
            this.mConnectThread.cancel();
            this.mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if(this.mConnectedThread != null) {
            this.mConnectedThread.cancel();
            this.mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        this.mConnectThread = new BluetoothService.ConnectThread(device);
        this.mConnectThread.start();
        this.setState(2);
    }

    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        Log.d("BluetoothService", "connected");
        if(this.mConnectThread != null) {
            this.mConnectThread.cancel();
            this.mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if(this.mConnectedThread != null) {
            this.mConnectedThread.cancel();
            this.mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if(this.mAcceptThread != null) {
            this.mAcceptThread.cancel();
            this.mAcceptThread = null;
        }

        this.mConnectedThread = new BluetoothService.ConnectedThread(socket);
        this.mConnectedThread.start();
        Message msg = this.mHandler.obtainMessage(4);
        this.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        this.setState(3);
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        Log.d("BluetoothService", "stop");
        this.setState(0);
        if(this.mConnectThread != null) {
            this.mConnectThread.cancel();
            this.mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if(this.mConnectedThread != null) {
            this.mConnectedThread.cancel();
            this.mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if(this.mAcceptThread != null) {
            this.mAcceptThread.cancel();
            this.mAcceptThread = null;
        }

    }

    public void write(byte[] out) {
        BluetoothService.ConnectedThread r;
        synchronized(this) {
            if(this.mState != 3) {
                return;
            }

            r = this.mConnectedThread;
        }

        r.write(out);
    }

    private void connectionFailed() {
        this.setState(1);
        Message msg = this.mHandler.obtainMessage(6);
        this.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private void connectionLost() {
        Message msg = this.mHandler.obtainMessage(5);
        this.mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            try {
                tmp = BluetoothService.this.mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("BTPrinter", BluetoothService.MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException var4) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "listen() failed", var4);
            }

            this.mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.d("BluetoothService", "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            this.setName("AcceptThread");
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            while(BluetoothService.this.mState != 3) {
                Log.d("AcceptThread线程运行", "正在运行......");

                try {
                    socket = this.mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException var6) {
                    Log.e("BluetoothService", "accept() failed", var6);
                    break;
                }

                if(socket != null) {
                    BluetoothService e = BluetoothService.this;
                    synchronized(BluetoothService.this) {
                        switch(BluetoothService.this.mState) {
                            case 0:
                            case 3:
                                try {
                                    socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException var4) {
                                    Log.e("BluetoothService", "Could not close unwanted socket", var4);
                                }
                                break;
                            case 1:
                            case 2:
                                BluetoothService.this.connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.i("BluetoothService", "END mAcceptThread");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d("BluetoothService", "cancel " + this);

            try {
                this.mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException var2) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "close() of server failed", var2);
            }

        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            this.mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BluetoothService.MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException var5) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "create() failed", var5);
            }

            this.mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i("BluetoothService", "BEGIN mConnectThread");
            this.setName("ConnectThread");
            BluetoothService.this.mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                this.mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException var5) {
                BluetoothService.this.connectionFailed();

                try {
                    this.mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException var3) {
                    Log.e("BluetoothService", "unable to close() socket during connection failure", var3);
                }

                BluetoothService.this.start();
                return;
            }

            BluetoothService e = BluetoothService.this;
            synchronized(BluetoothService.this) {
                BluetoothService.this.mConnectThread = null;
            }

            BluetoothService.this.connected(this.mmSocket, this.mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                this.mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException var2) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "close() of connect socket failed", var2);
            }

        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d("BluetoothService", "create ConnectedThread");
            this.mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException var6) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "temp sockets not created", var6);
            }

            this.mmInStream = tmpIn;
            this.mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.d("ConnectedThread线程运行", "正在运行......");
            Log.i("BluetoothService", "BEGIN mConnectedThread");

            try {
                while(true) {
                    byte[] e = new byte[256];
                    int bytes = this.mmInStream.read(e);
                    if(bytes <= 0) {
                        Log.e("BluetoothService", "disconnected");
                        BluetoothService.this.connectionLost();
                        if(BluetoothService.this.mState != 0) {
                            Log.e("BluetoothService", "disconnected");
                            BluetoothService.this.start();
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    BluetoothService.this.mHandler.obtainMessage(2, bytes, -1, e).sendToTarget();
                }
            } catch (IOException var3) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "disconnected", var3);
                BluetoothService.this.connectionLost();
                if(BluetoothService.this.mState != 0) {
                    BluetoothService.this.start();
                }
            }

        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                this.mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                BluetoothService.this.mHandler.obtainMessage(3, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException var3) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "Exception during write", var3);
            }

        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                this.mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException var2) {
                Log.e("BluetoothService", "close() of connect socket failed", var2);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, communication with BLE devices requires you to use the BluetoothGatt class.

Comment: Thanks Emil..I have 2 questions from your answer that : 1) Is it possible to implement SPP(Serial Port Profile) on the BLE 4.2 module side?  2)If possible, what if BLE 4.2 module on the other side has implemented SPP(Serial Port Profile) but not GATT? Will it be called as BT Classic communication or BLE communication ?

Comment: I have confusion in BLE that whether it supports BT classic  way or not

Comment: Treat BLE as a completely different thing than Bluetooth Classic. The SPP is defined for Bluetooth Classic only. There are of course similar services for BLE, but you need a completely different implementation since that would be GATT-based.

Comment: I don't know where I can ask this question so posting in comment:- Is there any Bluetooth Simulator Windows PC app to test Bluetooth?